# User-Defined Format does not update data set

Tags: sas

I have a format step as follows

```
proc format;
     value boolean
           -1 = 'invalid'
            1 = 'true'
            2 = 'false';

     value placement
           -1 = 'invalid'
            1 = 'first'
            2 = 'second'
            3 = 'third'
            4 = 'fourth';
run;
```

When i apply the boolean format to a variable in my data step, everything is replaced, including the -1 values. When I apply the placement format to a variable, everything is replaced except for the -1 values. Is there a reason why -1 works for one user-defined format but not the other?

Comment: Could be a few reasons for this, however you need to provide a bit more information first.  Can you post the code you are using to apply the formats, along with the variable type it is being applied to (I assume numeric, but need to check).  A snippet of the log may also help identify the cause.

Comment: You need to include example code of this not working.  Make an example dataset and show that it doesn't work...  and double check that `placement` is being applied to a numeric field, and not a character field - and additionally, that you're not inputting a character to numeric and truncating the `-` sign accidentally.